# SSRS: parameter not showing in url

Tags: url, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

In my tablix, my textbox has a custom expression. It is basically a URL:

```
=iif(Fields!permitNumber.Value="","<span style=visibility: hidden></span>","<a href=http://server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Reporting/Detailed&paramNumber=" & Fields!Number.Value & ">" & Fields!Number.Value & "</a>")
```

It is showing up properly as a URL but for some reason, the link shows everything except the paramNumber(or the equal sign). So I tried to include it manually ..Detailed&paramNumber=ABC123 and still does not show the parameter. So I thought maybe it's an URL Encoding issue so changed the equal sign to:

```
paramNumber%3D" & Fields!Number.Value & ">"
```

Now the parameter shows but the %3D fails to load the report. If I change %3D to = in the browser, it loads fine! What is the trick to make this thing include "=" and parameter and why does it stop at the equal sign?

BTW, why I am doing it this way? Action, Go to report allows me to go to a report but it creates a link even when there is no data(I don't want uses to accidentally click this link!). Trying to hide this link(the textbox) unexpectedly hides the border as well. Haven't figured out a way around this. One post suggests inserting a rectangle and a textbox but the rectangle size does not look to be dynamic scale(haven't really tested).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was able to create a placeholder, Action = Go to Url, put the link and parameter in there. Solved. Here the parameter shows up just fine. So apparently, the equal was being interpreted weirdly.

Comment: I think you may be able to get around it by concatenating Chr(61) in place of the "=" signs. Not sure why it is happening specifically, but I suspect it interprets the = uniquely because it is required at the start of all expressions.